# How to change default token provider in Identity service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-3.0

I Have 2 projects API and Auth Server using asp.net core 3.1 .  In API project am using identity server 4 token validation  to validate token . i am also Using identity  in API project.

Below code for token vaidation in api project

```
 var authAuthority = "https://localhost:5000";   // Configuration["BlazorBoilerplate:IS4ApplicationUrl"].TrimEnd('/');

       var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = authAuthority;
           options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.ApiName = "weatherapi";
       });
```

[image: my user claims]

After token validation user claims are showing  in httpContext.User.Identity object. Pls refer screen shot.

If i added  identity service to below code in ConfigureServices class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
          .AddRoles<Role>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CBSContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }
```

After addition of above asp.net identity service  , AuthorizationHandlerContext is showing empty.. Is there any relation between identity service and identity server token validation.

1. User authentication in Auth server   ---Working perfectly
2. I need to use user/role manager of identity in API project.
    I just wanted to change services.AddDefaultIdentity to  i identity server jwt validation how to do that?

   Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

*> After addition of above asp.net identity service ,

> httpContext.User.Identity (cliams) is showing empty.. Is there any
>   relation between identity service and identity server token
>   validation. Please suggest..*
>   Yes:
>   Refer to this image: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/middleware.png
>   (reminder https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/protocols.png)

When you add:

`services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
          .AddRoles<Role>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CBSContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

to your API, you are also saying that you store the tokens your self. Remember Authentication and Authorization are two different concepts (for more info: [Big Picture](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html))

You can use authentication in your API to i.ex. verify that a caller is who the caller is (Identity). But run your *authorization* server else where where you validate as you said.

But when you that code you are saying that you store your token in that DBContext.

You can have Authz. and Authn. on your API and use this for say clients login and claims etc. But you can also say that you rely on a different server for the Authz. part so that you federate that check.
*(Sorry for the long answer, my first response on SO)*

Comment: @Thanks  a lot..Actually  in  Auth server  project authentication (only login) working perfectly...but i need user creation,  role creatition etc in API so i need identity in API also..  How to use user/ role manager  in API project ..?

Comment: I have updated the question ..pls check ...I need Identity service only to  user and role creation not for authentication...

Comment: You need to use UserManager and RoleManager via Dependecy Injection(DI) in your front-end:
[ASP.NET Core with Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)